# Printing all the Python built-in sub-modules and functions of a builtin module

Tags: python

I want to print all the available functions and sub-modules in a built-in module.
For example:

```
dir(__import__("sys"))
```

It gives a list of classes and methods.

```
['__displayhook__',
'__doc__',
'__egginsert',
'__excepthook__',
'__name__',
'__package__',
'__plen',
'__stderr__',
'__stdin__',
'__stdout__',
'argv',
'builtin_module_names',
'byteorder',
'call_tracing',
'stdin',
'stdout',
'subversion',
'version',
'version_info',
'warnoptions',
'winver'] ...etc
```

but what i want is , I want to check all the available methods inside the class **sys.stdin** i.e.

**sys.stdin** constains the following functions like

```
sys.stdin.close  
sys.stdin.name       
sys.stdin.softspace  
sys.stdin.readline  
sys.stdin.readlines  
sys.stdin.seek  ...etc
```

So how to print all the availbale methods of a sub-module class.
I'm curious on how to implement this.
Thanks.
EDIT:

```
module_name = "sys" #module is taken from the user
smod ="stdin" # select the desire sub-module
param = module_name + smod
def printFns(param):
     #code to print all the available functions
```

Comment: Try to iterate on each and test it with hasattr(item, '__call__') and isinstance(item, types.FunctionType) after importing types

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same method that you used for `sys` module.
i.e.

```
>>> import sys
>>> dir(sys.stdin)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__in
educe__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed'
'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspa
'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

Comment: is it possible to pass as a string so that i can iterate on all the sub-modules and print their corresponding functions?

Comment: I've added an edit. I want to take the module name from the user and print with it.